# Enable caching for NGINX third party proxy

Tags: nginx, caching, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to avoid hitting a third party API too often by caching the response and avoiding the `429` responses we're getting from the API endpoint.

To accomplish this I've set up a Linode server running Ubuntu 20.04.

The config file `etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf` is as follows

```
server {
        server_name myserver-name-proxy.server.com;
        access_log /var/log/access.log main;
        error_log /var/log/error.log info;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_cache my_cache;
                proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
                proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD POST;
                proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
                proxy_cache_background_update on;
                proxy_cache_lock on;
                add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
                proxy_pass https://www.thirdpartyserver.com;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
                proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_buffering on;
                proxy_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$request_uri;
}
        default_type application/json;

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver-name-proxy.server.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver-name-proxy.server.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = myserver-name-proxy.server.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        server_name myserver-name-proxy.server.com;

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Then the config file `etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf` is

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent $request_time "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" "$upstream_cache_status" "$http_x_cache_status"';

    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=10g inactive=24h use_temp_path=off;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

There are no errors, yet when I `tail` the access log files or check the headers there is only `MISS` coming back from NGINX as the `$http_x_cache_status`

So far I've tried changing the `proxy_cache_path` to a new folder. When restarting this folder is created by the NGINX server but nothing is ever written to it plus a number of other things like switchin goff the background update, the cache lock etc etc.

The only difference I can see between this and all the tutorials out there is that I'm using this with SSL and hitting a https:// endpoing and using the `proxy_ssl_session_reuse` and `proxy_ssl_server_name` in the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two issues with this.

Firstly, the response from the upstream server was not returning any expire headers so NGINX will not cache those items. I was also setting `proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;`.

To ensure that NGINX sets cache on these requestes you need to include `proxy_cache_valid`.

This worked for one endpoint, but my other endpoint was still failing.

The second reason was because the origin/upstream server was responding with a `Set-Cookie` header which meant the response was not being cached.  To fix this I needed to also add `Set-Cookie` to the `proxy_ignore_headers`.

My final rule set was

```
       location / {
                proxy_pass https://www.thirdpartyserver.com;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_cache nft_cache;
                proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Set-Cookie;
                proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD POST;
                proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_429;
                proxy_cache_background_update on;
                proxy_cache_lock on;
                add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
                proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                proxy_ssl_verify off;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_buffering on;
                proxy_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$request_uri;
                proxy_cache_valid 10080m;
```

One other update I made was for the server that was caching the POST requests. Because the URL never changes you should update the `proxy_cache_key` to also include the `$request_body`

`proxy_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$request_uri$request_body;`

This means that you can hit the same post endpoint with different request bodies and know that you're going to catch the right responses (this was done using a GraphQL endpoint, not for posting forms).

***--Edit--***

I noticed that on some `POST` requests the cache was being skipped again. It turned out that this was because the `proxy_buffer` size wasn't large enough to contain the request.  I also had to include

```
proxy_buffers 8 32k;
proxy_buffer_size 64k;
```